# how to secure WordPress from DDOS attack?

Tags: wordpress, dns, cpanel

I have a DDOS attack on my website even it is properly firewall with Sucuri.net

Can anyone help me how to protect my server from DDOS because it shuts down entire server

Thanks

Comment: That this is a wordpress site is irrelevant, and a firewall is not really enough/appropriate for handling denial of service attacks. This is a job for a network administrator to handle. Consider using a service like Cloudflare if you're having trouble with this.

Answer (score 0):

If hacker attack on your wp-admin url then you can set password in wp-admin directory. Then you can avoid DDOS attack on your website.

**Set password in wp-admin in apache.**

htpasswd -c /etc/httpd/.htpasswd admin

**Add below code in your .htaccess file**

AuthName "Restricted Area"

AuthType Basic

AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd

AuthGroupFile /dev/null

require valid-user